# Topology on dual of an abelian discrete topological group.

Tags: harmonic-analysis

We define the compact-open topology on the dual of an abelian
topological group. Please describe compact open topology more explicitly in the case where G is equipped
with the discrete topology, for example G=Z.  Are the sup-norm topology and compact-open topology coincide on dual of Z?

Comment: The compact subsets of a discrete space are the finite subsets. So in this case the compact-open topology is just the pointwise convergence topology.